# overloading operator in D

Tags: d

I am trying to overload `+` but I got the errors:

```
@Error1 Error: no [] operator overload for type main.Matrix
```

Besides, I also got errors for measuring the time.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.c.process;
import std.date;
//@Error2

class Matrix
{
    Matrix opBinary(string op)(Matrix another)
    {
        if(op == "+")
        {
            if (row != another.row || col != another.col)
            {
                // error
                getchar();
                return (this);
            }

            Matrix temp = new Matrix(row, col);

            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                    temp[i][j] = this[i][j] + another[i][j];
                    //@Error1

            return temp;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: std.date was removed a few years ago, replaced with std.datetime, and you didn't overload the index operator yet tried to use it. Did you intend to access the double array yourself?

Comment: Yes. How do I change the data of the array? I am not sure how to overload index operator

Comment: Protip: replace `if(op == "+")`, etc with `static if(op == "+")`, since `op` is a template parameter and is known at compile time.

Comment: thanks, but static if gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> m2[i][j] = this[i][j] + b[i][j];
> ```

You must define `opIndex` to use operations like this. E.g.:

```
double[] opIndex(size_t i1)
{
    return d[i1];
}

double opIndex(size_t i1, size_t i2)
{
    return d[i1][i2];
}
```

Or just inside of that method you might want to access `double[][]` directly:

```
m2.d[i][j] = this.d[i][j] + b.d[i][j];
```

> ```
> std.date.d_time starttime = getCount();
> ```

Use [StopWatch](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_datetime.html#StopWatch). E.g.:

```
StopWatch sw;
sw.start();

// operations...

sw.stop();
writefln("elapsed time = %s", sw.peek().msecs);
```